# Android Pager Sliding TabStrip with dialog fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Here is what am trying to do. I  have pager sliding tab strip. It works perfectly. When a user selects my menu it pops up a dialog fragment with list view. which also works fine. Now my problem is that once the user selects or click on the item in the pop up dialog fragment, I want he/she to be returned or navigate back to the pager sliding strip tab fragment. In other words i want to hand over control back to the pager sliding strip tab. How do i achieve this.?  Thank you.

Comment: Post code. Post code. Post code.

Comment: everything in the code seems to work pretty fine, i was just looking for a way to hand over control back to the pager sliding strip tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
listeView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
     dismisse();             
}
});
```

Comment: thank you. seemed to have worked. just a quick one. In a pager sliding tab strip, how do you navigate from one tab to another with an Onclick button.

Comment: if you use `viewpager` then `viewPager.setCurrentItem( your tab number );`